# Combining addClass with fadeIn on mouseenter

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have written JavaScript code that uses the JQuery library to swap classes on hover.

```
$("#workBG").on({
mouseenter : function() {
  $("#workplay").addClass("workBG", 200);
  $("#workplay").removeClass("diagR", 200);
}
,
mouseleave : function() {
  $("#workplay").addClass("diagR", 200);
  $("#workplay").removeClass("workBG", 200);
 }
})
```

This code works but I would like to have the class fadeIn and fadeOut considering that it swaps background images but it does so harshly without the fadeIn and fadeOut. I have seen similar questions but they were all from five or six years ago and I would like to know if there is any better way to do this now.

From one of the older questions, I saw that they had answered with

```
.addClass("workBG", 200);
```

where the 200 is the time for the class to fadeIn. As far as I can tell, this does not work now or I am doing something wrong. I did check the JQuery documentation and there was nothing about this under the addClass API documentation.

In Addition:

HTML code:

```
<div id="workplay" class ="row text-center mt-5 diagR">
  <div class ="col-sm-6 align-self-center changework">
    <p id= "workBG" class ="display-1 font-weight-bold text-warning">WORK.</p>
  </div>
  <div class ="col-sm-6 align-self-center">
    <p id= "playBG" class ="display-1 font-weight-bold">PLAY.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the html code that is related to the JS and the backgrounds are applied through the classes.

Comment: Could you add a sample of your HTML too please. This may be possible in CSS alone, depending on how the `#workBG` and `#workplay` elements are related

Comment: use fadeIn() or fadeOut function instead of this if you are showing or hiding element otherwise add transition property

Comment: Also, the second integer argument to `addClass()` only works when you use jQueryUI.

Comment: Something alike `#workBG{transition:all 0.1s linear;} #workBG:hover{add your CSS from .workBG here}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add [transition](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) property on your element don't use 2nd parameter with addClass / removeClass function

```js
$("#workBG").on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $("#workplay").addClass("workBG");
    $("#workplay").removeClass("diagR");
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $("#workplay").addClass("diagR");
    $("#workplay").removeClass("workBG");
  }
})
```

```css
#workplay {
  transition: 2s;
}

.workBG {
  background: red;
}

.diagR {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="workBG">
  <div id="workplay">asdasdasd</div>
</div>
```

Comment: OH, I tried applying this fix but I added transition under my .workBG classes and that hadn't worked. A little bit of CSS goes a long way :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

/* This is working fine for me, Please try this solution */

```
    $("#workplay").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $("#workplay").fadeIn("slow", function() {
            $("#workplay").addClass("workBG");
            $("#workplay").removeClass("diagR");
        });
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $("#workplay").fadeIn("slow", function() {
            $("#workplay").addClass("diagR");
            $("#workplay").removeClass("workBG");
        });
    }
});
```

/* You can run this file as it is (It is working fine) */

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#workplay").on({
            mouseenter: function() {
                $("#workplay").fadeIn("slow", function() {
                    $("#workplay").addClass("workBG");
                    $("#workplay").removeClass("diagR");
                });
            },
            mouseleave: function() {
                $("#workplay").fadeIn("slow", function() {
                    $("#workplay").addClass("diagR");
                    $("#workplay").removeClass("workBG");
                });
            }
        })
    });
    </script>
    <style>
    #workplay {
      transition: 2s;
    }
    .workBG {
      background: red;
    }
    .diagR {
      background: blue;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="workplay">
      Please move cursor on me.
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```